# React HOC returns before async function can run

Tags: reactjs, async-await, higher-order-components

I'm trying to implement a protected route HOC in React, but I'm having some trouble with an asynchronous call.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ Component, acceptedRoles }: ProtectedRouteProps) => {
  return function WrappedRoute(props: JSX.IntrinsicAttributes) {
    const [renderedPage, setRenderedPage] = useState(<></>);

    useEffect(() => {
      async () => {
        const pageToRender = await getPageToRender(
          props,
          acceptedRoles,
          Component
        );
        setRenderedPage(pageToRender);
      };
    }, [props]);

    return renderedPage;
  };
};
```

The is an async API call inside getPageToRender, which is why I have to use await. However, getPageToRender is just never called and the rendered component is never updated. Without the async call everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the anonymous function. You can do like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const pageToRender = await getPageToRender(
          props,
          acceptedRoles,
          Component
        );
        setRenderedPage(pageToRender);
      })();
    }, [props]);
```